# Structure needed for dynamic behaviour

Tags: c#, design-patterns, unity-game-engine, structure

I am using Unity to build a visualisation of a serious game. I am using C# programming language.

My problem is that I receive data from a JSON and I parse it and I end up with a list of different 'words' saying for example:

Player - walks to - Carl

or

Carl - says ... to - Player

(note that this list is not limited to 3 words, it can be a longer statement, and it doew not HAVE to contain Player or NPC or whatever, it's very flexible)

I have a list containing all the possible actions & NPC names , so Carl in this example, would be in my NPC list of names so I can recognize him as an NPC. Same goes for the 'actions' to perform.

However now i need to map a lot of these different actions to visualisations in the game itself.

Thus I think I need a way to store:

1) the order of the words

2) the 'meaning' (NPC or Player or Action)

3) the word itself

Can anyone point me in the direction of a very efficient structure or design pattern to use to make this work? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have your own *Domain Specific Language* (DSL).

Maybe one of these may help you get started:

- [Getting Started with Domain-Specific Languages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee943825.aspx)
- [How to: Create a Domain-Specific Language Solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126593.aspx)
- [Writing Your First Domain Specific Language](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26975/Writing-Your-First-Domain-Specific-Language-Part)

Comment: Yea! However, I am not the one creating those JSON's (they get generated from the DSL), i just use them and parse them into Unity :)Thanks for the links!